# Deploy dacpac fails with compatibility set to 130

Tags: sql-server

When we do a build with dacpac, there is a timeout error connecting to the server when the compatibility level is set to 130 on **one** of the databases. The process builds just fine as long as the one database is set to compatibility level 100. That is where it used to be.

- We use SQL Server 2016
- This is the `sqlpackage` executable:
  `C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft SQL Server\130\DAC\bin\sqlpackage.exe`

Am I missing settings or something else on the database that would cause this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I added `/p:CommandTimeout="0"`  to what I run through a batch file:

```
C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft SQL Server\130\DAC\bin\sqlpackage.exe
```

...and it worked right away.

I had already updated the registry and added other switches with no success.

Comment: When you say "it worked", do you mean it ran for an excessive amount of time and then succeeded, or it succeeded in a "normal" amount of time? I would have thought increasing the timeout might allow it to complete successfully, but wouldn't resolve the root issues that the query was taking a long time to execute?

Comment: @UberDoodles Normal amount of time. This is what I remember. I’m not at that company anymore so can’t double check

Answer (score 2):

I had (have) this same problem.

When the dacpac generates the script, it queries the target database to see what objects are there. One or more of those queries went from sub second to much longer, when we moved to 2016. By updating the statistics of some system tables I was able to bring it back down to normal behavior.

```
update statistics sys.sysschobjs;
update statistics sys.sysobjvalues;
update statistics sys.sysidxstats;
update statistics sys.syssingleobjrefs;
```

So, I don’t know exactly what changed to make SQL Server run those queries slowly, but this is how we've solved the problem.

Comment: I didn't try updating the system stats before adding this line :  /p:CommandTimeout="0"

Comment: We have had this problem for several months. In our case, setting compatibility mode to 120 was enough to work around it, but this obviously isn't a long-term solution. When it was originally investigated, updating the statistics resolved it. But it then re-appeared a while later, and this time refreshing the statistics didn't resolve it.